# How can I animate Matrix4.identity using a Vector2 or Vector3 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to move my **object in flutter along the X and Y**. I am doing this using **AnimatedBuilder and Matrix4.identity** in flutter.

(and a few other animations which results in the widget moving up and the opacity fading in at the same time).

My animation is working all fine. The issue I have been trying to fix is I need to create two animation values for the X and Y axis separately, then pass them into translate property.

From my research, I understand I should instead be using a **Vector2 or Vector3** object instead to pass into the translate property. But I cant seem to make this work.

I even tried creating my own custom Vector2 class then run a Tween on this but this failed.

I know this is a small issue, but I would like to be doing this the correct way / efficient way.

Thank you!

```
class _AnimatedFadeInState extends State<AnimatedFadeIn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _fade, _scale, _moveY, _moveX;

  @override
  void initState() {

    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget._duration),
        vsync: this);

    _fade = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Interval(0,0.50, curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic)));

   _scale = Tween<double>(begin: 0.90, end: 1.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));

//Can I tween a Vector2 or Vector3 here instead of tweening X and Y separately?
    _moveX = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));

    _moveY = Tween<double>(begin: 50, end: 0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));

    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..scale(_scale.value)
            ..translate(_moveX.value, _moveY.value), //can I pass in Vector2/3 here? (or similar).
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget._duration),
    child: widget._widget,
    opacity: _fade.value,

        ));},
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: actually you cannot use `Vector2` - check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4/translate.html. section `Implementation`

Comment: OK noted, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: but instead of creating a custom `Tween<Vector3>` why don't you use `Tween<Offset>`?

Comment: all you need is : `_offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, 50), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));` and use it like: `..translate(_offset.value.dx, _offset.value.dy)`

Comment: Thank you! I changed to Offset as per your advice, and it worked (I had originally tried Offset but had implemented it wrong so thought it didnt apply). This is great to know. Cheers.

Comment: and here you have a custom `Tween`: `class Vector3Tween extends Tween<Vector3> {
  Vector3Tween({ Vector3 begin, Vector3 end }) : super(begin: begin, end: end);

  @override
  Vector3 lerp(double t) {
    final x = begin.x + (end.x - begin.x) * t;
    final y = begin.y + (end.y - begin.y) * t;
    return Vector3(x, y, 0);
  }
}` - but i really dont think it pays off to do such thing